# Contact created from relationship tab is automatically tagged

Tags: relationships

When I create a new user from another contact's profile, in the relationship tab, the new contact automatically gets one of my tags... 
I have no idea where to look to solve this one.
Any clues?

Using civicrm 4.6.25

Comment: hmm - was sure I had already suggested you check if you have civirules in place. or did someone delete my comment?

Comment: also yossi - it helps everyone if you vote for answers and 'accept' best answers. looking at your profile looks like you have a fair number you have never gone back to.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, I do have Civirules but it isn't installed

Comment: I also went back and voted/accepted answers.

Comment: thanks for the voting/accepting. hmm. so you have 'something' doing 'something' that results in all new contacts getting Tagged? and you have checked your Extensions and any other Customisations?

Comment: is it possible to set a Tag as a default, and would that get triggered when you add new contact?

Comment: I've never seen such behavior in Civi not would I know how to reproduce it... I can solve it by simply deleting that tag but It's always best to try and get to the bottom of these things...

Comment: what about Drupal Rules - they could cause this

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found the cause by looking around, you can write an extension that uses `hook_civicrm_pre` on the Tag entity to call `CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()`.  That should show you what's calling the tag creation code.

Answer (score -1):

Go the Contact (the one you want to edit) > Tags. The Tag tab is toward the right side of the Contact categories.

Comment: your answer helps remove a tag once it has been added bu i think the question is about what mysterious process is auto tagging contacts when they are created

Comment: I thought they just wanted to delete an unwanted tag.